# How can early BIOS use CALL? (follow-up)

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, bios

This is a follow-up to [How can early BIOS use CALL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970485/how-can-early-bios-use-call), same ROM file, same setting.

Thanks to Brendan I know that upon a cold boot the jump discussed there would be taken and a call instruction would be skipped at that moment. But there are other memory writes soon after that. This is a shortened listing, the full thing with all complete branches (55 lines) can be found at https://pastebin.com/wfT4np5u:

```
[Beginning is the same as in the first question]
f000:e045  out 0x70, al  ; CMOS controller: disable NMI, set index 0xf
f000:e047  out 0xeb, al  ; this port is presumably unoccupied: just a delay mechanism
f000:e049  in al, 0x71   ; read 0xf (CMOS Shutdown Status)
f000:e04b  out 0xeb, al  ; more delay
f000:e04d  or al, al
f000:e04f  jmp 0xf483
f000:f483  jne 0xf488
[assuming status ≥ 0x0D (cold boot) – jump:]
f000:f488  mov ax, 0x40
f000:f48b  mov es, ax
f000:f48d  cmp word es:[0x72], 0x1234
f000:f494  je 0xf49b

[Scenario 1: we find word 0x1234 at 0040:0072:]
[some further tests, always jumping to f000:f4c8 if a condition fails; if all passes, the flow reaches that address linearly]

[Scenario 2: 0040:0072 does not return 0x1234:]
f000:f496  jmp 0x3253
f000:3253  jmp 0xf499
f000:f499  jmp 0xf4c8

[All cases now converge HERE]    <<<   This is the interesting bit
f000:f4c8  mov ax, 0x30
f000:f4cb  mov ss, ax
f000:f4cd  mov sp, 0x100
f000:f4d0  mov al, 0x8f
f000:f4d2  call 0xe415  ; Hi again, now I'm unconditional
```

Apparently Scenario 1 requires that some memory remained initialized from earlier (unless it's some kind of ROM mapped to segment 0x40), so in a cold boot scenario I think we can ignore that. But regardless of the branches taken at `f000:f494`, we arrive at `f000:f4c8`. This sets up SS:SP to `0030:0100` and proceeds to `call` something.

Is it possible that the motherboard has a little amount of "safety net" RAM mapped there that's available even if I take out all the memory banks? Or does BIOS expect that the first few kilobytes will be accessible in any possible setup? What happens if they aren't?

Comment: The Coreboot people told me that the machine either starts in or sets up a “cache as RAM” mechanism on boot where the CPU cache is used as RAM.  This is achieved by disabling cache write back without also disabling cache.

Comment: @fuz Interesting! I'll try to do a little research in that direction. What's strange is that I don't see anything that could initialize this, but maybe it's in some way implicit.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33193156/417501) might be interesting in this regard.

Comment: Also note you said it's an older bios so maybe back then cache as ram was not used. Instead the memory controller might have powered up with ram already initialized at some default settings.

Comment: That MB uses the bridge architecture (North and South bridge). The NB is the Intel 82845GE (G)MCH (Graphic and Memory Controller Hub) and its duty is to steer accesses to one of: Memory, AGP (external Video Card), Integrated Video Card or ICH4 (The South Bridge). Since it was a pre-multi-channel, pre-over-4GiB MCH, the config registers are limited and by default the `DRB[0:3]` regs are configured to route 32MiB of RAM. **But this is not enough**, particularly the DRAM timings defaults are invalid. So I don't think the RAM is accessed yet, the same for CRAM (Cache-as-RAM), which must be ...

Comment: ... set by tweaking `cr0`. What happen, to me, is that the read to the BDA Soft Reset flag (`0040:0072`) is simply terminated (either by the MCH or the ICH4) and `0xffff` is returned. Remember: Reading memory is not forbidden, even if the DRAM is not yet initialised (of course the read won't go to the DRAM). Fun, irrelevant, fact: Since Haswell `0xfffffff0` (aliased into `0xf000:fff0`) is not the boot entry point anymore. The boot is microcoded to reach for the FIT and load the Startup ACM in a secure environment (which includes CRAM). This is part of Intel TXT (BootGuard).

Comment: However, If you see a memory (not MMIO) store before the DRAM is initialised, we must be missing something. BTW, you probably want the chipset datasheets or the code will quickly become meaningless.